# Manga about a goddess/saintess who is helped through her depression by a crown prince or emperor

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

So the female lead is a goddess/saintess with black hair.

I’m almost certain she was just a normal girl who was summoned from another world by the church, and suffered from depression due to losing or not being able to see her old world anymore.

The male lead is either the crown prince or emperor and he falls in love with the goddess/saintess and helps her through her depression.

I remember that the manga had color in it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by _"losing her old world"_?

Comment: Sorry didn’t word that right I mean losing it as in not being able to see it anymore.. and no I remember it had color in it!

Comment: So was the female lead originally from another world? And did she have a different identity in that world?

Comment: Yes I’m almost certain she was just a normal girl and she was summoned by the church. Sorry I’ve been searching for it  for a while I have some blanks in my memory about it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[The Meaning of You](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ufnvipo/the-meaning-of-you)***...?

> Dayeon is… tired. She’s so tired that she’s been transported to a new world and she’s still too tired to do anything. But most of all, she’s tired of Emperor Mikhail’s near-constant attention! He’s just so perfect… always concerned about her well-being and shielding her from the church’s attempts to label her some kind of saint. And he keeps finding reasons to brush her hair behind her ear or stare dreamily into her eyes. How’s a girl supposed to sleep through all this endearingly loving attention?!

In her previous life, the female lead, Dayeon Lee, was a Korean office worker with dark hair who'd fallen into a state of depression. She then woke up in a forest in another world, where she was greeted by knights and taken to see the emperor of the Altius Empire, Mikhail Dnar Altius.

[image: The Meaning of You, chapter 1, page 5.]

The people in this world believe she's a goddess based on a divine revelation, however, she has no powers and the education she received in Korea isn't useful here (especially not for someone with the high expectations placed upon her). Despite this, the emperor provides her with a palace to stay in and servants to tend to her needs, but she continues to be depressed and becomes extremely lethargic, not wanting to get out of bed, bathe, or even eat properly.

[image: The Meaning of You, chapter 10, page 4 and 5.]

When the emperor learns of this, he takes a more active role in her life, ensuring that she's bathed properly, bringing in chefs to prepare more appealing meals for her, assigning a young priest as her personal tutor, and regularly checking in on her to provide encouragement. Over time, he also develops romantic feelings for her.